# GoLang send file via POST request

Tags: rest, post, go, webserver

I am new in GoLang language, and I want to create REST API WebServer for file uploading...

So I am stuck in main function (file uploading) via POST request to my server...

I have this line for calling upload function

```
router.POST("/upload", UploadFile)
```

and this is my upload function:

```
func UploadFile( w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params ) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Upload files\n")
    postFile( r.Form.Get("file"), "/uploads" )
}

func postFile(filename string, targetUrl string) error {
    bodyBuf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyBuf)

    // this step is very important
    fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile("file", filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error writing to buffer")
        return err
    }

    // open file handle
    fh, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening file")
        return err
    }

    //iocopy
    _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, fh)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bodyWriter.FormDataContentType()
    bodyWriter.Close()

    return err

}
```

but I can't see any uploaded files in my `/upload/` directory...

So what am I doing wrong?

P.S I am getting second error => `error opening file`, so I think something wrong in file uploading or getting file from `UploadFile` function, am I right? If yes, than how I can teancfer or get file from this function to `postFile` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.Open` will open a file, since the file doesn't exist you will get an error.
Use `os.Create` instead it will create a new file and open it. (ref: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open)

> **func Open**
>
> `func Open(name string) (*File, error)`
>
> Open opens the named file for
>   reading. If successful, methods on the returned file can be used for
>   reading; the associated file descriptor has mode O_RDONLY. If there is
>   an error, it will be of type *PathError.
>
> **func Create**
>
> `func Create(name string) (*File, error)`
>
> Create creates the named file with mode 0666 (before umask),
>   truncating it if it already exists. If successful, methods on the
>   returned File can be used for I/O; the associated file descriptor has
>   mode O_RDWR. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

**EDIT**

Made a new handler as an example:
And also using OpenFile as mentioned by: [GoLang send file via POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541656/golang-send-file-via-post-request/45541764?noredirect=1#comment78043634_45541764)

```
func Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Upload files\n")

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) //dont do this
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // copy example
    f, err := os.OpenFile(handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) //please dont
    }
    defer f.Close()
    io.Copy(f, file)

}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile allows you to make more accurate mode management than other functions.

Comment: ok, but how I can get file which I am sending to the server? because I can create file, but it's not the same which I am sending...

Answer (score 4):

The `multipart.Writer` *generates multipart messages*, this is not something you want to use for receiving a file from a client and saving it to disk.

Assuming you're uploading the file from a client, e.g. a browser, with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you should use [FormFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile) instead of `r.Form.Get` which returns a `*multipart.File` value that contains the content of the file the client sent and which you can use to write that content to disk with `io.Copy` or what not.